# Requirements for an invitation letter for an internship in Japan

Tags: visas, paperwork, japan

I have Indian nationality and I am planning to go to Japan for three months to do an internship at a university in Tokyo. I am going to apply for a Student Internship Visa for less than 90 days. In the requirements list for the visa application, it is written that I need to submit an original invitation letter from the calling institute. For some reason, the Japan Postal Service does not have air mail from Japan to India, so it will take two to three months for the document to reach.

I was planning to apply for the visa using the PDF that has been sent to me online; will that be acceptable?

Comment: There are tons of courier services that will be able to send it overnight or within 2 or 3 days. DHL, FedEx, UPS etc.